# django test model field

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

i'm currently writing tests for my django project and i need to make sure

that a specific field of a model is of a certain type.

for example in model Pictures i want to make sure that there is a field with the

name "image" and that he of type ImageField.

i also want to be able to check if an attribute is of type ForeignKey of

model Pictures.

i tried to use the assertIsInstance, but i need to assign the attribute or else

he is None.

does someone know how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, a check like this should work:

```py
from django.db.models import ImageField
from wherever.mymodels import Pictures
...
field = Pictures._meta.get_field("image")
assertTrue(isinstance(field, ImageField))
```

Though, for my 2¢, it may make more sense for your unit test to check that setting the "image" of some Picture instance works as-expected, rather than just checking for an ImageField named "image". After all, what you should really be checking with a test case is: "will the code I'm using to upload/validate/save images reliably work"?

Comment: it doesn't recognize "_meta"... do i need to import something?

Comment: You should just need a `from wherever.models import Pictures` and `from django.db.models import ImageField`. The `_meta` field of a Model should be supported on all [recent versions of Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/meta/).

Comment: do you know if there is a way to check if it has "null=True" or "blank=True"?

Comment: @brad yes, just check the "null" and "blank" attributes of the field: they will be True or False.

Comment: now you can also check it like self.assertIsInstance(field, ImageField)